# ifstream not working in my code

Tags: c++, ifstream

I am making a kind of bot and i need to get some values from a document. The document will be wrote with some "First Time Setup". Well, the problem is, the program is not reading the values.

```
ifstream inFile;
inFile.open("D:\Bot\bin\Debug\Settings.in");

inFile >> i >> i2;
cout<<"Retrieving data..."<<endl;
cout<<" "<<endl;
Sleep(10000);
cout<<"SO: "<<i<<endl;
cout<<"BO: "<<i2<<endl;
Sleep(2000);

inFile.close();
```

I used the location where the .exe is. I can't figure out why it's not getting the values. I get 0 for both variables. I tried with a .txt file. Same thing.

Comment: You should check if the file [`is_open()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ifstream/is_open)

Comment: 1. Probably, you meant `ini` file.
2. Probably, you have to escape slashes or use a raw-string literal.
3. Why don't you check if file is open?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

\ is escape character. To have it in string it should be:

```
inFile.open("D:\\Bot\\bin\\Debug\\Settings.in");
```

Comment: Or use a raw-string literal (since c++11) - `R"(D:\Bot\bin\Debug\Settings.in)"`.

Comment: @SerbanElyan It seems you are a novice here, the `accept button` under each answer marks that it helped to solve your problem. Use it.